# Defining an Ord instance for Maybe datatype

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Is this a minimal complete definition of an `Ord` instance for `Maybe` datatype ? Is it correct ?

```hs
instance Ord (Maybe a) where
  compare (Just x) (Just y) | x < y     = LT
                            | x > y     = GT
                            | otherwise = EQ
  compare _        _                    = LT
```

```hs
instance Ord (Maybe a) where
  (Just x) <= (Just y) = x <= y
  _            _       = False
```

Comment: You could write down those two functions (outside of an instance declaration, and with a different name to avoid some confusing errors) and ask QuickCheck whether they match the default implementations.

Comment: Wow, that's very interesting ! Thank you, @Daniel Wagner ! Could you tell me how can I ask QuickCheck what you suggest ?

Comment: Aside: when you write `x < y` or `x <= y`, how do you know that there are functions `(<)` and `(<=)` that you can use on x and y (both of which have type `a`)? You don't, unless you also know that there is an instance out there of `Ord` for `a`. So at a minimum, you need constraints on your instance: `instance Ord a => Ord (Maybe a) where ...`

Comment: @F.Zer Sure, once you named your implementation `fZer'sCompare` instead of `compare`, it would be something like `quickCheck (\x y -> compare x y == fZer'sCompare x (y :: Maybe Int))`.

Comment: Thank you, @Daniel Wagner. The compiler says: "fZer'sCompare’ is not a (visible) method of class ‘Ord’". How can I solve this ?

Comment: @F.Zer As I said in my original comment: "outside of an instance declaration".

Comment: Sorry about that, @Daniel Wagner. Now, it works perfectly !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it complete in the sense that it covers all possible pattern cases? Sure; you have a catch-all at the end of both definitions. However, it's not a very good `Ord` instance, given that it violates the [constraints set forth in the documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Ord).

> Transitivity
>
> if x <= y && y <= z = True, then x <= z = True
>
> Reflexivity
>
> x <= x = True
>
> Antisymmetry
>
> if x <= y && y <= x = True, then x == y = True

In particular, your second proposed relation is not reflexive, since `Nothing <= Nothing` is false. Your first relation is going to behave even more oddly, since `Nothing <= Nothing` will return true but `Nothing >= Nothing` will return false.

The built-in `Ord` instance for `Maybe` observes that `Maybe a` is isomorphic to `a`, plus an extra value we call `Nothing`, so it simply defines `Nothing` to be the minimum value for the ordering. The existing relation is equivalent to the following

```
instance Ord a => Ord (Maybe a) where
    compare Nothing Nothing = EQ
    compare Nothing (Just _) = LT
    compare (Just _) Nothing = GT
    compare (Just x) (Just y) = compare x y
```

Or, written in terms of `<=`,

```
instance Ord a => Ord (Maybe a) where
    Nothing <= _ = True
    Just _ <= Nothing = False
    Just x <= Just y = x <= y
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, @Silvio Mayolo. It is very clear !